# Cloned A Ruby on Rails App, But Confirmation Email Link Still Pointing To Old App Online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I just finished Railstutorial.org.  I now want to use that base application I built (a twitter clone) and build stuff on top of it.  I cloned the code into a new directory and am making modifications, but one issue I can't seem to figure out.  When I get the authentication email for the new app, when I click on the link in the email, it is still sending me to the original application.  Any suggestions on how I modify my code so that the link points to the correct new application?  I'm thinking it has to do with the authentification token and the database....

Comment: Searching your code for the wrong URL / domain should reveal the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  Between yours and Steve's responses, I got it fixed.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your config/envronments/production (or 'development')

You'll see a line like...

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }
```

Change it to the correct host.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks, Steve.  That was my first question ever on Stack Overflow.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  If you want to accept my answer, the option to accept it appears just to the left of the answer.